# Memcached set failes

Tags: php, memcached

i have an error in 4 lines script i cant find.
`

```
$m = new Memcached();
var_dump($m->addServer('localhost', 11211));
var_dump( $m->getResultCode());
var_dump($m->set("aaaa","bbb"));`
```

Output:

```
bool(true) 
int(0) 
bool(false)
```

get and replace also return false.

My mistake or misconfiguration of memcached server?

Comment: You sure that the memcached service is up on your localhost, I mean started? I think may be it is due to some misconfiguration of the server...

Comment: first 2 results say that server and connection are online

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have the same issue...